# Qué significa Class<?> en Java?

Tags: java, poo

No he encontrado un ejemplo con `<?>` Porque no simplemente utilizar class como parámetro?

Comment: <> Quiere decir que no esta definido el tipo de dato Ejemplo: List<personas> quiere decir que la List es de tipo personas.

Answer (score 4):

Regularmente puedes ver algo como `Class<String>` que indica que String es el tipo de clase de modelado por el objeto Class.

En base a tu pregunta, puedes usar  `< ? >` si se desconoce la clase que esta siendo modelada: `Class<?>`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

Comment: ¿Eso es un Template?

Answer (score 1):

Es una abreviatura de

```
< ? expande Object >
```

Así podemos especificar cualquier tipo de objeto.

Por ejemplo, la clase List está declarada como:

```
List < ? >
```

Ya que con la lista podemos hacer lo que queramos.

Answer (score 1):

Class es lo que se llama un genérico (generic en ingles). Genéricos se usan para declarar Clases que sirven para manejar objetos de una variedad de clases.

Por ejemplo, si uno implementa una lista, generalmente a la lista no importa todo lo que se puede hacer con los objetos adentro, pero si puede interesar que solamente se pueden juntar objetos del mismo tipo/subtipo.

Entonces una implementación de na lista se implementa con un genérico. Comparemos:

```
// creamos una lista para documentos sin genéricos
List lista = new ArrayList();
Doc documento = new Doc(file);
lista.add(documento);
// mas adelante en el código...
// el compilador no permite eso, porque no `get(indice)` devuelve `Object`
Doc primerdoc = list.get(0);
// entonces tenemos que hacer un cast
Doc primerdoc = (Doc) list.get(indice);
// o, porque eso podría salir con un `ClassCastException`
Object o = list get(indice);
Doc primerdoc;
if (o instanceof Doc) primerdoc = o;
```

Para todo el resto de código, el método para obtener un elemento de la lista es

```
public Object get(ìnt indice)
```

Con genéricos cambia el asunto:

```
List<Doc> lista = new ArrayList<Doc>();
// Eso ya no va funcionar, ya antes del tiempo de ejecución:
lista.add("Eso no es un documento");
// pero eso si
lista.add(new Doc(file));
// y más adelante:
Doc primerdoc = lista.get(0);
```

Aqui no se necesita un cast, porque para el mundo el método `get`de la lista ha cambiado a:

```
public Doc get(int indice);
```

En el caso concreto, `Class<?>` por ejemplo se encuentra en Javadocs para declarar que el resultado puede ser cualquier clase.

**Por la pregunta si `<?>` sería lo mismo que `<T>`:**

Las letras en genéricos se usan como variable a una clase. Por ejemplo, si declaro:

```
public interface MiInterfaz<T>{
    public T getContenido();
}
```

significa que si implemento una clase con `implements MiInterfaz<String>`, el mètodo para implementar sería `public String getContenido(){}`.

La notación `<?>` es un "wildcard" - un joker - no enlazado , que representa una clase no definida en este formato.

Otras notaciones son:

- `<? extends T>` - enlazado para arriba: una clase no definida que extende o implementa  clase o interfaz T (no necesariamente directamente).
- `<? super T>` - enlazado para abajo, captura clase T o sus superclases.

Comment: seria lo mismo `<T>`?